# How to place marginal notes in a center column between two independent text columns

Tags: babel, multicol, geometry, polyglossia

I have looked at `\usepackage{multicol}` and several other options, but none seems to provide a layout like this. Being still fairly new to LaTeX, I hardly know where to look for more information. Many packages seem to exist, so I am hoping someone here knows of one that addresses this requirement.

Please see the attached image for an example of the dual-language layout I seek with marginal references centered, for one language only, between them.

[image: Image of three columns of text, with right and left columns being separate languages with matching content, and a smaller center column between, separated by line dividers, for marginal references for one language only.]

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the pair of packages `reledmac` and `reledpar` (successors to `eledmac` and `eledpar`, which succeeded `ledmac` and `ledpar`).

Here is a simple example, but note that many other modifications are possible.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{reledmac,reledpar}

\usepackage[latin,british]{babel}% just for this example
\usepackage{ragged2e}% \RaggedLeft = better line-breaking

\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.4\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.4\textwidth}
\setlength{\ledlsnotewidth}{0.1\textwidth}
\renewcommand*{\ledlsnotefontsetup}{\RaggedLeft\footnotesize\sffamily}
\leftnoteupfalse% aligns start of note with position in main text; can
                % be a problem at the bottom of the page (but the
                % reverse causes problems at the top of a page)

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}
  \begin{Leftside}
    \selectlanguage{latin}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart

    {[1]} His ita gestis, accidit ut peccarent duo eunuchi, pincerna
    regis Aegypti, et pistor, domino suo. [2] Iratusque contra eos
    Pharao (nam alter pincernis praeerat, alter pistoribus), [3] misit
    eos in carcerem principis militum, in quo erat vinctus et
    Joseph. [4] At custos carceris tradidit eos Joseph, qui et
    ministrabat eis: aliquantulum temporis fluxerat, et illi in
    custodia tenebantur. [5] Videruntque ambo somnium nocte una, juxta
    interpretationem congruam sibi:

    [6] ad quos cum introisset Joseph mane, et vidisset eos tristes,
    [7] sciscitatus est eos, dicens: Cur tristior est hodie solito
    facies vestra? [8] Qui responderunt: Somnium vidimus, et non est
    qui interpretetur nobis. Dixitque ad eos Joseph: Numquid non Dei
    est interpretatio? referte mihi quid videritis. [9] Narravit
    prior, praepositus pincernarum, somnium suum: Videbam coram me
    vitem, [10] in qua erant tres propagines, crescere paulatim in
    gemmas, et post flores uvas maturescere:

    [11] calicemque Pharaonis in manu mea: tuli ergo uvas, et expressi
    in calicem quem tenebam, et tradidi poculum Pharaoni. [12]
    Respondit Joseph: Haec est interpretatio somnii: tres propagines,
    tres adhuc dies sunt: [13] post quos recordabitur Pharao
    ministerii tui, et restituet te in gradum pristinum: dabisque ei
    calicem juxta officium tuum, sicut ante facere consueveras. [14]
    Tantum memento mei, cum bene tibi fuerit, et facias mecum
    misericordiam: ut suggeras Pharaoni ut educat me de isto carcere:
    [15] quia furto sublatus sum de terra Hebraeorum, et hic innocens
    in lacum missus sum.

    [16] Videns pistorum magister quod prudenter somnium dissolvisset,
    ait: Et ego vidi somnium: quod tria canistra farinae haberem super
    caput meum: [17] et in uno canistro quod erat excelsius, portare
    me omnes cibos qui fiunt arte pistoria, avesque comedere ex
    eo. [18] Respondit Joseph: Haec est interpretatio somnii: tria
    canistra, tres adhuc dies sunt: [19] post quos auferet Pharao
    caput tuum, ac suspendet te in cruce, et lacerabunt volucres
    carnes tuas. [20] Exinde dies tertius natalitius Pharaonis erat:
    qui faciens grande convivium pueris suis, recordatus est inter
    epulas magistri pincernarum, et pistorum principis.

    [21] Restituitque alterum in locum suum, ut porrigeret ei poculum:
    [22] alterum suspendit in patibulo, ut conjectoris veritas
    probaretur. [23] Et tamen succedentibus prosperis, praepositus
    pincernarum oblitus est interpretis sui.

    \pend
    \endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart

    \ledleftnote{The first verse.}%
    {[1]} After this, it came to pass, that two eunuchs, the butler
    and the baker of the king of Egypt, offended their lord. [2] And
    Pharao being angry with them (now the one was chief butler, the
    other chief baker) [3] He sent them to the prison of the commander
    of the soldiers, in which Joseph also was prisoner, [4] But the
    keeper of the prison delivered them to Joseph, and he served
    them. Some little time passed, and they were kept in custody. [5]
    And they both dreamed a dream the same night, according to the
    interpretation agreeing to themselves:

    [6] And when Joseph was come in to them in the morning, and saw
    them sad, [7] He asked them, saying: Why is your countenance
    sadder today than usual? [8] They answered: We have dreamed a
    dream, and there is nobody to interpret it to us. And Joseph said
    to them: \ledleftnote{Doth not interpretation belong to God?: When
      dreams are from God, as these were, the interpretation of them
      is a gift of
      God.}%
    Doth not interpretation belong to God? Tell me what you have
    dreamed. [9] The chief butler first told his dream: I saw before
    me a vine, [10] On which were three branches, which by little and
    little sent out buds, and after the blossoms brought forth ripe
    grapes:

    [11] And the cup of Pharao was in my hand: and I took the grapes,
    and pressed them into the cup which I held, and I gave the cup to
    Pharao. [12] Joseph answered: This is the interpretation of the
    dream: The three branches are yet three days: [13] After which
    Pharao will remember thy service, and will restore thee to thy
    former place: and thou shalt present him the cup according to thy
    office, as before thou wast wont to do. [14] Only remember me,
    when it shall be well with thee, and do me this kindness: to put
    Pharao in mind to take me out of this prison: [15] For I was
    stolen away out of the land of the Hebrews, and here without any
    fault was cast into the dungeon.

    \ledleftnote{This is the verse about the chief baker}%
    [16] The chief baker seeing that he had wisely interpreted the
    dream, said: I also dreamed a dream, That I had three baskets of
    meal upon my head: [17] And that in one basket which was
    uppermost, I carried all meats that are made by the art of baking,
    and that the birds ate out of it. [18] Joseph answered: This is
    the interpretation of the dream: The three baskets are yet three
    days: [19] After which Pharao will take thy head from thee, and
    hang thee on a cross, and the birds shall tear thy flesh. [20] The
    third day after this was the birthday of Pharao: and he made a
    great feast for his servants, and at the banquet remembered the
    chief butler, and the chief baker.

    \ledleftnote{This is verse 21}%
    [21] And he restored the one to his place to present him the cup:
    [22] The other he hanged on a gibbet, that the truth of the
    interpreter might be shewn. [23] But the chief butler, when things
    prospered with him, forgot his interpreter.  \pend
    \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

[image: reledpar example image]

Comment: I now get a message that says it cannot find the package.  I have tried installing it, and copied the directory to various locations on my Mac, to no avail.  I'm no newbie to computers, which is why this is so frustrating--just new to LaTex, obviously.  So the "LaTex for Dummies" question: how do I install reledmac?

Comment: Ha, well although my laptop is currently a Mac, I have LInux installed, so I don't know the *exact* details of how to do it. The dumb-but-easy answer is to put the packages in the current working folder while you figure out how to do it properly.  (I think you can also use `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFDIST` (to find the 'system'-level paths. But I remember OSX fairly recently made accessing core folders more difficult so that might not work. There is also `TEXMFLOCAL` and `TEXMFHOME`.)

Comment: For me, those three commands return: `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist`, `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`, `~/texmf`. Given this information, I'd do (for `TEXMFHOME`, say) `mkdir -p ~/texmf/tex/latex/{reledmac,reledpar}` and install the respective `.sty` files there. (Note: you must make the directory tree mimic the expected structure: `$TEXMF/tex/latex/<package>` for the files to be found.)

Comment: And to try to find the package, there is `kpsewhich reledmac.sty`. If your installation is quite old, you might still find `eledmac.sty` that way (`kpsewhich eledmac.sty`) or `ledmac.sty` if *really* old (in TeX Live terms).

Comment: I have MacOSX 10.8.5.  The commands gave me as follows:

sh-3.2# kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFDIST
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist

sh-3.2# kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local

sh-3.2# kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME
/var/root/Library/texmf

But that last directory does not appear to exist on my system.  Copying the reledmac folder into the other two did not solve the problem.

Comment: Once you install to `...DIST` or `...LOCAL`, you may need to do `texhash` so TeX can find the new files (on my system, I need admin privileges to do that: `sudo texhash`). You need -- if you want it -- to create your `...HOME` folders. Looks like you'd need to do `mkdir -p /var/root/Library/texmf/tex/latex/reledmac` and put the `.sty` files there. The home folder does not need `texhash`.

Comment: I can easily find eledmac.sty.  It now exists in multiple places on my hard drive.  However, Tex does not find it.  I do not know how to inform Tex of its location.

Comment: Do not confuse **e**ledmac.sty with **re**ledmac.sty. And did you simply put the files in the folder with the actual `.tex` file for now? I am not qualified to give Mac-specific installation instructions. (Though I am fairly certain that everything I told you applies to OSX too.)

Comment: I can get the script to compile by manually entering the paths for each .sty file during compilation.  Perhaps that will have to do for now.  Thank you.

Comment: That sounds like an extremely annoying way to do anything, and I don't recommend it as a work flow.  But I'm at a loss as to what to suggest since it's not clear which parts of my advice you've followed or where precisely you've installed things, and I'm not sure what you mean about 'manually entering the paths'. (But, if you're happy, so be it!)