# Place margin notes between columns (with twocolumn)

Tags: two-column, marginpar

In my `twocolumn` document, I want to place the margin notes between the two columns. The (reasonable) default is to place them in the margins of the page. `\reversemarginpar` seems to have no effect with `twocolumn`.

```
\documentclass[landscape, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{mwe} % only for blind text

\setlength\columnsep{3cm}
\setlength\marginparwidth{1cm}
\setlength\marginparsep{.3cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\marginpar{first margin paragraph}

\lipsum[2-3]
\marginpar{second margin paragraph}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image: The output of the MWE above.]

How can I place the margin notes in the margin between the columns?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353948/134144 Here you can find an answer on how to achieve the desired output using the `reledmac` and `reledpar` packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does no checks on whether the notes will overprint, just swaps the side.

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{mwe} % only for blind text
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setlength\columnsep{3cm}
\setlength\marginparwidth{1cm}
\setlength\marginparsep{.3cm}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@addmarginpar{\if@firstcolumn}{\if@firstcolumn\else}
   {\typeout{yes}}{\typeout{no}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\marginpar{first margin paragraph}

\lipsum[2-3]
\marginpar{second margin paragraph}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```