# Margin notes in center column with multicol

Tags: multicol, marginnote

There are at least two questions ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424303/place-margin-notes-between-columns-with-twocolumn) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395205/two-column-document-with-annotations-between-columns)) on how to get center column margin notes with the `twocolumn` layout and `\marginpar`. But how would I do this in a `multicols` environment? The `marginnote` package allows margin notes in `multicols`, is there some way to hack `\marginnote` like `\marginpar`?

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435131/117534)?

Comment: Generally speaking: Yes, there is.

Comment: @Troy My previous question was about how to get notes of some kind (maybe margin notes, maybe not) in the center column. This question is specifically about hacking `marginnotes`. The answer to this question could help with answering my other question, but not vice versa.

Comment: You could use two columns (e.g. with class option `twocolumn` instead of `multicol` package) only with a large gap in between (e.g. increasing `\columnsep`) and use [`scrlayer-notecolumn`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-notecolumn) with either a relocated default note column or a newly defined one in the gap between the two standard columns. You can also use `scrlayer` to define an additional layer with the two vertical rules. Otherwise you would have to patch the horizontal placement calculation of `marginnote` in `\@mn@@@marginnote`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Thank you! Both options look promising. I tried to create a test of `scrlayer-notecolumn` but I couldn't get the notes anywhere except the outer margin (I've never used KOMA-Script before so maybe I missed something in the 500+ page manual). Having never patched an existing command I haven't tried the other option.